# Shared variables in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I am trying to create multiple threads of `bot` and they share some variables, but I am failing miserably in getingt the shared variables to work.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
import sys
import threading
import signal
import time

class bot(threading.Thread):
    terminate = False
    #def __init__(self):
    #   threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    #   self.terminate = False

    def getCode():
        code_lock.acquire()
        work_code = code
        try:
            code += 1
        finally:
            code_lock.release()
        return work_code

    def checkCode(code):
        try:
            #if(code % 1000000 == 0):
            print("Code "+str(code)+" is being checked...\n")
            html = requests.get(url+str(code))
            html.encoding = 'utf-8'
            return not 'Page Not Found' in html.text
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            print("Connection Error! Retrying...\n")
            time.sleep(0.5)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            logCode(code)
            sys.exit()

    def storeCode(code):
        file_lock.acquire()
        try:
            file.write(code+'\n')
        finally:
            file_lock.release()

    def logCode(code):
        log_lock.acquire()
        try:
            log.write(code+'\n')
        finally:
            log_lock.release()

    #def run(self):
    #   global bots
    #   global url
    #   global file
    #   global log
    #   global code_lock
    #   global file_lock
    #   global log_lock
    while(not terminate):
        code = getCode()
        if(checkCode(code)):
            storeCode(code)
    logCode(code)


def main(code = 0, threads = 16):

    #bots = [threading.Thread(target=bot) for bot in range(threads)]
    bots = []
    url = 'https://test.ing/codes/'
    file = open("valid-codes.txt", "a")
    log = open("log.txt", "a")
    code_lock = threading.Lock()
    file_lock = threading.Lock()
    log_lock = threading.Lock()

    def signal_handler(signal, frame):
        print('Exiting...\n')
        log_lock.acquire()
        try:
            log.write("\n\n"+str(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime()))+"\n")
        finally:
            log_lock.release()
        for bot in bots:
            bot.terminate = True
        for bot in bots:
            bot.join()
        sys.exit(0)

    #for bot in bots:
    #    bot.start()

    for i in range(threads):
        t = bot()
        bots.append(t)
        t.start()

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    while True:
        signal.pause()

main(736479509787350, 1)
```

With this code I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "bot.py", line 7, in
>
> ```
> class bot(threading.Thread):   File "bot.py", line 59, in bot
>
> code = getCode()   File "bot.py", line 14, in getCode
>
> code_lock.acquire() NameError: name 'code_lock' is not defined
> ```

I don't know if I should override the `run(self)` method of `bot`, but when I tried that it never actually ran the method `run` and I also receive the same error from all the threads created: that `int` is not callable (and I can't see where I can possibly be using an int as object).

Additionaly I don't know if I am handling correctly the exit signal from keyboard, as you can see I am trying to deal with that using a `terminate` variable, but I don't think that this is the problem...

One last thing, the `ConnectionError` exception is not being appropriately handled, as it's saying "Retrying...", but in fact it will not retry, but I am aware of that and it should be ok, I'll fix it latter.

Worth mentioning that I'm not very used to deal with multi-threading and when I do deal with it, it is in C or C++.

### Edit

I can make the code work by using global variables, but I do not want to do that, I prefer to avoid using globals. My attempts of passing the variables directly to the instances of the class `bot` or by passing an data-object to it weren't successful so far, whenever I pass the variables or the auxiliar object to `bot` I am unable to access them as attributes using `self.` and without `self.` Python claims that the variable was not defined.

Here is the updated code, without success yet:

```
import requests
import sys
import threading
import signal
import time

class Shared:
    def __init__(self, code, url, file, log, code_lock, file_lock, log_lock):
        self.code = code
        self.url = url
        self.file = file
        self.log = log
        self.code_lock = code_lock
        self.file_lock = file_lock
        self.log_lock = log_lock

class bot(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, data):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.terminate = False
        self.data = data

    @classmethod
    def getCode(self):
        self.data.code_lock.acquire()
        work_code = self.data.code
        try:
            self.data.code += 1
        finally:
            self.data.code_lock.release()
        return work_code

    @classmethod
    def checkCode(self, work_code):
        try:
            #if(code % 1000000 == 0):
            print("Code "+str(work_code)+" is being checked...\n")
            html = requests.get(self.data.url+str(work_code))
            html.encoding = 'utf-8'
            return not 'Page Not Found' in html.text
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            print("Connection Error! Retrying...\n")
            time.sleep(0.5)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.logCode(work_code)
            sys.exit()

    @classmethod
    def storeCode(self, work_code):
        self.data.file_lock.acquire()
        try:
            self.data.file.write(work_code+'\n')
        finally:
            self.data.file_lock.release()

    @classmethod
    def logCode(self, work_code):
        self.data.log_lock.acquire()
        try:
            self.data.log.write(work_code+'\n')
        finally:
            self.data.log_lock.release()

    @classmethod
    def run(self):
        while(not self.terminate):
            work_code = self.getCode()
            if(self.checkCode(work_code)):
                self.storeCode(work_code)
        self.logCode(work_code)


def main(code = 0, threads = 16):

    #bots = [threading.Thread(target=bot) for bot in range(threads)]
    bots = []
    url = 'https://www.test.ing/codes/'
    file = open("valid-codes.txt", "a")
    log = open("log.txt", "a")
    code_lock = threading.Lock()
    file_lock = threading.Lock()
    log_lock = threading.Lock()

    data = Shared(code, url, file, log, code_lock, file_lock, log_lock)

    def signal_handler(signal, frame):
        print('Exiting...\n')
        log_lock.acquire()
        try:
            log.write("\n\n"+str(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime()))+"\n")
        finally:
            log_lock.release()
        for bot in bots:
            bot.terminate = True
        for bot in bots:
            bot.join()
        sys.exit(0)

    #for bot in bots:
    #    bot.start()

    for i in range(threads):
        t = bot(data)
        bots.append(t)
        t.start()

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    while True:
        signal.pause()

main(736479509787350, 4)
```

Yet, the working code with global variables:

```
import requests
import sys
import threading
import signal
import time

code = 736479509787350
url = 'https://www.test.ing/codes/'
file = open("valid-codes.txt", "a")
log = open("log.txt", "a")
code_lock = threading.Lock()
file_lock = threading.Lock()
log_lock = threading.Lock()

terminate = False

class bot(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    @classmethod
    def getCode(self):
        global code
        code_lock.acquire()
        work_code = code
        try:
            code += 1
        finally:
            code_lock.release()
        return work_code

    @classmethod
    def checkCode(self, work_code):
        try:
            if(code % 1000000 == 0):
                print("Code "+str(work_code)+" is being checked...\n")
            html = requests.get(url+str(work_code))
            html.encoding = 'utf-8'
            if(not 'Page Not Found' in html.text):
                time.sleep(0.5)
                html = requests.get(url+str(work_code)+":999999999")
                html.encoding = 'utf-8'
                return 'Page Not Found' in html.text
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            #print("Connection Error! Retrying...\n")
            time.sleep(1)
            return self.checkCode(work_code)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.logCode(work_code)
            sys.exit()

    @classmethod
    def storeCode(self, work_code):
        global file_lock
        global file
        file_lock.acquire()
        try:
            file.write(str(work_code)+'\n')
        finally:
            file_lock.release()

    @classmethod
    def logCode(self, work_code):
        global log_lock
        global log
        log_lock.acquire()
        try:
            log.write(str(work_code)+'\n')
        finally:
            log_lock.release()

    @classmethod
    def run(self):
        global terminate
        while(not terminate):
            work_code = self.getCode()
            if(self.checkCode(work_code)):
                print("Code "+str(work_code)+" is a valid code!\n")
                self.storeCode(work_code)
        self.logCode(work_code)


def main(threads = 16):

    #bots = [threading.Thread(target=bot) for bot in range(threads)]
    bots = []
    #url = 'https://www.facebook.com/leticia.m.demenezes/posts/'
    #file = open("valid-codes.txt", "a")
    #log = open("log.txt", "a")
    #code_lock = threading.Lock()
    #file_lock = threading.Lock()
    #log_lock = threading.Lock()

    def signal_handler(signal, frame):
        global terminate
        print('Exiting...\n')
        log_lock.acquire()
        try:
            log.write("\n\n"+str(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime()))+"\n")
        finally:
            log_lock.release()
        terminate = True
        for bot in bots:
            bot.join()
        sys.exit(0)

    #for bot in bots:
    #    bot.start()

    for i in range(threads):
        t = bot()
        bots.append(t)
        t.start()

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    while True:
        signal.pause()

main()
```

Comment: Side-note: _Always_ use `with` statements with locks. It's much more obvious what is protected, much harder to get wrong and much simpler. `with code_lock:` followed by a block containing the protected accesses is much simpler than an explicit `.acquire()`, followed by a `try` block with the protected accesses and a `finally` with an explicit `.release()`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks! I wasn't aware of that, great to know!

Answer (score 1):

You could make the `code_lock` global as you're trying to do, but why not just pass it into each `bot` class?

```
t = bot(code_lock)
```

Next create a constructor for your class:

```
class bot(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, code_lock):
       threading.Thread.__init__(self)
       self.code_lock = code_lock
```

Now, whenever you try to use `code_lock` inside your `bot` class, always prefix it with `self` (`self.code_lock`).

If you really insist on using global variables, then look into the [`global` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4693385/276949).

Comment: Yes, I made them global once and the code worked, but I am not for using globals. I tried to pass each variable to the class (I think that a problem would appear when passing `code` as it would be passed by value) and I also tried creating an object to hold the necessary arguments, but I seem to be unable to access the passed object (or variables when tried then individually) within the class methods. I will update my question to reflect that. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: And one more thing, when you make `self.code_lock = code_lock`, will changes in the instance's `code_lock` affect the other instances' `code_lock`s? I fear you are making `code_lock` local, thus independent, to each bot instance. I want `code_lock` to be a shared variable.

Comment: Nope, `code_local` is not becoming local. There is only one copy and that it when you do `code_lock = threading.Lock()`. After that you are only passing around *references* to this single lock object.

Comment: For your updated question, use `self.code_lock.acquire()` instead of `self.data.code_lock.acquire()`

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that you are trying to access `code_lock` out of it's scope, may be you can follow #MartinKonecny suggestion to fix that.

I could see that even after fixing `code_lock` problem, your code has lot of problems. as soon as you fix `code_lock` problem you'll face similar issue with the variable `code` in the same function `getCode`.

After fixing all those `compiled` time issues, you'll face issues with your whole `class` implementation, this is not the way to implement `Python` classes.

It's better that you go through [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) to know more about python `name spaces` and `classes`.

Comment: Well, I think you are right, I am not doing such a pythonic class implementation, I think I am failing dealing with that because I'm just seeing the class as a thread, as if the inside of the class was just a plain new file to write my Python code into it. I think I should not be creating methods and using them within the class, maybe I am carrying habits of C++ namespaces. But what else should I do?